# What should be the system configuration (for server) when my web appn need to run atleast 25 parallel selenium remotewebdriver executions?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, tomcat6, selenium-grid

What should be the system configuration (for server) when my web appn need to run atleast 25 parallel selenium remotewebdriver executions?

Current Configuration: Windows7, 4GB RAM, 1.7 GHZ Processor, Tomcat 6, Java 7.

I am facing out of memory issue if no of executions exceeds 10.

Following are the commands to start HUB and NODE:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role hub

java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=iexplore,version=10,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=10,-maxSession=10, -browser  browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=10,-maxSession=10, -browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=10,-maxSession=10, -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="./IEDriverServer32.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="./chromedriver.exe" -port 5559
```

I starts HUB and NODE at client machine. So there are 25 client machines and a server.

Following is the code to launch browser at client machine:

```
URL hubUrl = new URL("http://10.253.**.***:4444/wd/hub");
WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(hubUrl, capabilities);
webDriver.get(sURLToLaunch);
```

I suspect there is need of server class machine. I will be grateful if you will give your opinion.

Comment: I will appreciate your view.

Comment: i would suggest to separate the nodes and the hub.
What worked well for me was 3 instances per machine with 2gb memory and 1 core cpu.

Comment: Thanks Urb. What I am planing is only 1 browser instance per client machine and several such client connected to server at a time. I want to increase concurrent client count upto 25.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras, it will help you manage your grid much more easily

Comment: Thanks Urb. Let me go thru..